# How to find the number of divisors that are perfect squares and divisible by a number

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Suppose $ n = 2^{14}  3^{9} 5^{8} 7^{10} 11^{3} 13^{5} 37^{10}  $ , find the number of positive divisors that are both perfect squares and divisible by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$.

It is quite simple to find both the perfect squares and the number of divisors divisible by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$separately. But I am confused on how to combine these two properties into one.

To find the number of perfect perfect squares, I find the largest perfect square that is possible and find the maximum combination of perfect square divisors.

> $ 2^{14}  3^{8} 5^{8} 7^{10} 11^{2} 13^{4} 37^{10}  $ is the largest perfect square.
>
> The largest perfect square can also be written as $((2^{2})^{7}*(3^{2})^{4}*(5^{2})^{4}*(7^{2})^{5}*(11^{2})^{1}*(13^{2})^{2}*(37^{2})^{5}$.
>
> The amount of combinations of the perfect squares is $ (7+1) * (4+1) * (4+1) * (5+1) * (1+1) * (2+1) * (5+1) = 43200$

To find the number of divisors divisible by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$, I divide $ 2^{14}  3^{9} 5^{8} 7^{10} 11^{3} 13^{5} 37^{10}$ by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ which leaves a remainder and the combinations of the remainder is the number of divisors divisible by $2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$.

> $ 2^{14}  3^{9} 5^{8} 7^{10} 11^{3} 13^{5} 37^{10}$ / $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ = $2^{12} 3^{5} 5^{6} 7^{10} 11^{0} 13^{5} 37^{10} $
>
> The amount of combinations divisible by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ is $ (12+1) * (5+1) * (6+1) * (10+1) * (0+1) * (5+1) * (10+1) = 396396$

I have tried to find both the perfect squares and the number of divisors divisible by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ combined by first finding the largest perfects square and then dividing it by $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$. With the remainder, I find the number of combinations with it.

> $(2^{2})^{7}*(3^{2})^{4}*(5^{2})^{4}*(7^{2})^{5}*(11^{2})^{1}*(13^{2})^{2}*(37^{2})^{5}$ / $ 2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ = $(2^{2})^{6}*(3^{2})^{2}*(5^{2})^{3}*(7^{2})^{5}*(11^{2})^{0}*(13^{2})^{2}*(37^{2})^{5}$
>
> The amount of combinations is $ (6+1) * (2+1) * (3+1) * (5+1) * (0+1) * (2+1) * (5+1) = 9072$

The number 9072 appears to be incorrect however, as I have tried this method with smaller numbers and always ending up with a result that was off.

Any ideas on how  find the number of divisors that are perfect squares **and** divisible by a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any perfect square $S$ has even multiplicity of any given prime number, so if it divides $n = 2^{14}  3^{9} 5^{8} 7^{10} 11^{3} 13^{5} 37^{10}$ it in fact must divide $n' = 2^{14}  3^8 5^8 7^{10} 11^2 13^4 37^{10}$ (all exponents rounded down to even). Now if the perfect square $d=2^{2}3^{4}5^{2}11^{2}$ divides $S$, then $S/d$ is integer and still a perfect square, and it divides $n'/S=2^{12}3^45^67^{10}13^4 37^{10}=m$. Then $\sqrt{S/n'}$ is *any* divisor of $\sqrt m=2^63^25^37^513^237^5$. You can count those divisors. You did. $9072$ is the right answer.

If you've encountered a smaller example where this approach does not give the right answer, why not present the details of *that* case?

Comment: I tried a case with 99 and finding the divisors that are perfect squares and divisible by 5. Using the same approach does not seem to work as the prime factorization of 99 is $11^{1} 3^{2}$. When you divide that by 5, you are left with still $11^{1} 3^{2}$ and can be written as $11^{1} 3^{2} 5^{1}$. And the biggest perfect square divisor of that is $(3^{2})^{1}$, finding the combinations, we can see that this is not the right case which left me question myself.

Comment: I don't understand the special case. There aren't _any_ divisors of $99$ that are divisible by $5$, even without requiring a perfect square. And in any case, for a perfect square to be divisible by $5$, it must be divisible by $25$. So for the forced divisor, you do "round up to even" for multiplicities. This does not play a role in the actual question, since as noted in the answer $d$ is already a perfect square.